Re-using same page within navigation with Expo Router (React-Native)
I have a question. I have navigation to the same page (i currently copy and paste the same code into 2 different files in 2 different folders) but if i try to put the page in one central location, then the back button displays the wrong navigation title. I'll post my file tree. The goal is to navigate to [gameId] from both the calendar folder index.tsx and also from the home index.tsx -- but the main thing being, that whichever screen it came from, is what shows on the back button. i can't figure this out. the navigation gets super wonky. Home, Calendar, and Profile are all tabs on a tab bar and ChatGPT nor Claude can correctly fix it how I'm looking.


app/
├─ (admin)/
│  └─ _layout.tsx
├─ (auth)/
│  ├─ changepassword.tsx
│  └─ login.tsx
├─ (protected)/
│  ├─ _layout.tsx
│  ├─ calendar/
│  │  ├─ [gameId].tsx
│  │  ├─ _layout.tsx
│  │  └─ index.tsx
│  ├─ home/
│  │  ├─ AllGames/
│  │  │  └─ index.tsx
│  │  ├─ SituationBook.tsx
│  │  ├─ [gameId].tsx
│  │  ├─ _layout.tsx
│  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  └─ rulebook.tsx
│  ├─ profile.tsx
│  └─ roster/
│     ├─ _layout.tsx
│     ├─ details.tsx
│     └─ index.tsx
├─ _layout.tsx
└─ index.tsx



